# How to create an address of tezos by using pytezos?

Tags: account, python

I've created an address of tezos by using pytezos with the below mentioned code

```
addr = Key.generate()
publicKey = addr.public_key_hash()
pvtKey = addr.secret_key(passphrase='12435')
```

and when I import the above generated address in Temple wallet by using the pvtKey it's imported correctly but when I've sign the transaction with private key and I used my generated pvtKey it thorws an error of wrong pvt key and then I've imported the private key of above generated address from my temple wallet I've got the different pvt key and it's working fine I'm not getting why it's happening?

Answer (score 1):

`pytezos.using` expects a `private key` as `key` parameter. In the example above you are providing the public key hash, which is incorrect.

```
:param key: 
  base58 encoded key, path to the faucet file, faucet file itself, alias from tezos-client, or **Key**
```

```
client = pytezos.using(shell='https://rpc.kathmandunet.teztnets.xyz', key= "<private_key>")
```

Comment: Actually I'm using kukai wallet and I'm not getting my private key it's only giving me my secret phrase.how could I find my private key?

Comment: I've created another account on Temple Wallet and in the code I've used the private key of my account in key but still I'm getting the hash of operation but it's not including.

Comment: Do you have balance in that account that you created? Also try to do `<client>.transaction(...).send(min_confirmations=1)`, it will wait for the operation to be confirmed in a block.

Comment: I've 6001 tez and I'm doing it on kathmandu net

Comment: here's my code now

opg = pytezos.using(shell='https://rpc.kathmandunet.teztnets.xyz', key= "edskRuKSyPoztVVFvbFmeSMmkDLBc9fun1xtwTVJVFnSqv8fsegtHmnhCyao7Pdi8wa2yeEcB5iPURAwgnJrq8qSdPyNj7AYWZ")

opg1 = pytezos.transaction(destination='tz1WvwfBrGkeum9McZgaBXUt7iTvkvQHjjVT', amount=Decimal('12')).fill().sign().inject()

Comment: Look at what I wrote above. `opg.transaction(destination='tz1WvwfBrGkeum9McZgaBXUt7iTvkvQHjjVT', amount=Decimal('12')).send(min_confirmations=1)`

Comment: it's still not including

Comment: code is here



opg = pytezos.using(shell='https://rpc.kathmandunet.teztnets.xyz', key= "edskRuKSyPoztVVFvbFmeSMmkDLBc9fun1xtwTVJVFnSqv8fsegtHmnhCyao7Pdi8wa2yeEcB5iPURAwgnJrq8qSdPyNj7AYWZ")

opg1 = pytezos.transaction(destination='tz1WvwfBrGkeum9McZgaBXUt7iTvkvQHjjVT', amount=Decimal('12')).send(min_confirmations=1)

Comment: replace `pytezos` with `opg` on the second line

Comment: it's throwing this error

pytezos.rpc.node.RpcError: ({'id': 'failure',
  'kind': 'temporary',
  'msg': 'Error while applying operation '
         'onewNdesFZGtMLnYBY4bjacJVdkZvQZ8jtQm6aTrvEoToP2vCwu:\n'
         'Error:\n'
         '  Unrevealed manager key for contract '
         'tz1RsunQa8nMKTG1BbQNxZN4p4Usx9AZrZWZ.\n'},)

Comment: That means you need to reveal the account public key. https://pytezos.org/quick_start.html#reveal-public-key

Comment: I've used this code now

opg = pytezos.using(shell='https://rpc.kathmandunet.teztnets.xyz', key= "edskRuKSyPoztVVFvbFmeSMmkDLBc9fun1xtwTVJVFnSqv8fsegtHmnhCyao7Pdi8wa2yeEcB5iPURAwgnJrq8qSdPyNj7AYWZ")

opg1 = opg.transaction(destination='tz1VVPnvHfCNVUtPfYbMfmxZsCrpCvbjFpVY', amount=Decimal('15')).reveal().fill().sign().inject()

Comment: It's throwing this error now

pytezos.rpc.node.RpcError: ({'id': 'failure',
  'kind': 'temporary',
  'msg': 'Error while applying operation '
         'onsb4Kxo1drp5oa6NhuXRYfXAQMHbbHZKmdnWeSMgQoisgxmJ4t:\n'
         'Error:\n'
         '  Incorrect reveal operation position in batch: only allowed in '
         'first position.\n'},)